# Build a super lightweight version of QGIS

Tags: qgis, tools, qgis-customization, build

I'm looking for a way to create a QGIS build with a minimal set of specific tools. I want to use it with my custom script that allows the user to:

1. Create a new project
2. Add offline OSM tiles
3. Put a few points here and there (through the *Digitizing panel* or the *NumericalDigitize* plugin)
4. Automatically draw lines between them
5. Save the result

The problem is that I don't know what modules and libraries are needed for this purpose and, hence, I don't know what to include in the build (and how to properly do that).

At first, I thought I could achieve this with help of **OSGeo4W** (*Advanced* installation) but I was quickly overwhelmed with a long list of libraries listed. So then I started looking for a guide on QGIS modules which I could bundle together, but found nothing.

Does anybody know how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Have you tried modifying user profiles?

Comment: @Erik Sure, but what I want to truly achieve is a package that will occupy less space on the workstation. I don't want it to have extra modules that I will never use.

Comment: Seems really complicated and unlikely to reduce the size by a whole lot since you still need most of the big "pieces" of QGIS and its not like QGIS takes that much space anyway

Comment: @LouisCottereau I thought such things as Raster, Web, DB and Mesh tools should occupy significant amount of disk space, but if it's not the case (or is it?) then you're right. There's no point in fiddling with the build itself.

Comment: If that's all the functionality you need you could probably do it without QGIS, using a browser-based front end and a fairly simple server running locally.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for the idea. Indeed, it might be an option though the big question on how to properly build up your own Qgis is still open. Based on the feedback from the community I now feel like it's something way beyond our powers :-)

Comment: QGIS ist opensource and there are some companies offering Support, including core contributers who know the Code and architecture of the Software (I'm not affiliated to any). You could hire one of them to do the job for you. See https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/commercial_support.html

Comment: The cmake file allows you to chose which module to install or not. Some are needed for the base stuff  (QGIS core), another also could be to create a standalone application that doesn't need to be installed and could be accessed on a shared drive (the ming64 action on github create such an 'artefact'). But if you just want a project you could probably generate one without qgis by replicating the internal content with the layers you want, might be a hassle though.